# Как предоставить пользователю полный доступ к системе macOS?

Tags: macos, ос, root, macbook

У меня есть своя пользовательская запись в операционной системе macOS мне нужно чтобы данный пользователь имел доступ ко всему, и имел право на редактирование всего?
То есть нужно чтобы он был как суперпользователь?

Comment: Достаточно возможности выполнять `sudo`...

Comment: Мне нужно выполнять без команди sudo, потому что есть ряд дальнейших проблем(

Comment: Если вы можете выполнить `sudo bash`, то в этой новой оболочке вы сможете уже делать что угодно...